# Finding a basis of a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Can you please help me with this task?

> Let $f_1=\cos 2x,f_2=\sin x,f_3=\sin^2x$. Consider the linear space $\mathbb{W}=\left\langle f_1,f_2,f_3\right\rangle$.
>
> Let $\mathbb{U}=\{f\in\mathbb{W}|f(0)=0\}$. Find a basis of this subspace.

I have proved that $f_1, f_2, f_3$ are linearly independent by considering the equation
$$a\cos(2x)+b\sin(x)+c\sin^2(x)=0$$
How do I find a basis? Should I substitute $0$ into $x$?

Comment: Well...have you got a sense of what dimension $\mathbb U$ might have?  Could it be $3$ dimensional?

Comment: @lulu no( i don't understand how to do the task( could you explain please if you know

Comment: You need to show some effort.  This is a very basic exercise...you'll be able to solve it if you try.  What dimension does $\mathbb W$ have?

Comment: i suppose it is 3?

Comment: It has a basis with three elements, so yes.  Now, if $\mathbb U$ had dimension $3$, what would that mean?

Comment: it's a span of three linearly independent vectors?

Comment: Well....can a $3$ dimensional vector space have a proper $3$ dimensional subspace?

Comment: three dimensional subspace of U is itself, so i suppose it can and basis is just f1,f2 and f3. Or is my assumption incorrect?

Comment: So, if $\mathbb U$ had dimension $3$, it would have to be all of $\mathbb W$, right?  Can it be all of $\mathbb W$?  Does it contain each of $f_1, f_2, f_3$?

Comment: so that's what I don't know. maybe i should try to express some of f through each other?

Comment: To test each basis vector, you only need to check to see whether $f_i(0)=0$.  This has nothing to do with independence.

Comment: so the basis would consist just of f which satisfy equation f(0)=0? like sinx and (sinx)ˆ2

Comment: Well, no.  In principle there is no reason at all for the basis of $\mathbb U$ to be part of the given basis of $\mathbb W$.  But this problem is especially easy, so it happens to be true in this case.

Comment: Each element in $\mathbb{W}$ is of the form $f(x)=a\cdot \cos(2x)+b\cdot \sin(x)+c\cdot \sin^2 (x)$. Requiring $f(0)=0$ gives $a=0$, so $f_2, f_3$ is a good basis for $\mathbb{U}$. 
Obviously this is not a general method, and the basis of the subspace is not necessarily a subset of the basis of the space.

Comment: So, for each specific case we should check individually? Like if f(pi/4)=0, then cos 2x is a basis?

Comment: Again, there is no reason for the basis of $\mathbb U$ to be part of the given basis.  Say you look at the polynomials of degree $≤2$, for which a basis is $\{1,x,x^2\}$.  Then you can ask for the subspace for which $p(1)=0$.  No basis functions satisfy this, but the subspace is not empty (it contains both $x-1$ and $x^2-1$).

Comment: thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

This problem is somewhat easier than the general problem of this type because it happens that a good basis for $\mathbb U$ is a subset of the given basis for $\mathbb W$.

Indeed, both $f_2$ and $f_3$ are in $\mathbb U$ so $\mathbb U$ contains the $2$ dimensional subspace spanned by $f_2,f_3$.  Now that has to be all of $\mathbb U$ since if $\mathbb U$ contained anything else it would have dimension $3$ hence would be all of $\mathbb W$, but $f_1\not \in \mathbb U$ so this is not possible.

In general, there is no reason for a basis of $\mathbb U$ to be a subset of the given basis, but it is the case here.